# Drag and Drop pin on google map manually and get Lon & Lat in google map APIV2

Tags: java, android, latitude-longitude, google-maps-api-2

i'm new to google maps api V2. I want a functionality like, on the page it has to display the map and there has to be a marker in the map and the map has to be draggable and by dragging it has to display the dragged location's latitude and longitude.. Can anyone plz help me to solve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the docs... https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#marker_drag_events

To get the final position, just call `marker.getPosition()` in the `onMarkerDragEnd` method.